# How to customize flash message based on success or failure with Inherited Resources Rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources, ruby-on-rails-plugins, inherited

I'm using the inherited resources plugin in a 2.3.5 Rails application and was wondering how to change the flash[:notice] (or any other flash) based on the success OR failure in my create and update actions.

So given the below, how do I add flash[:notice] = "All good" if success ... and flash[:notice] = "All bad" if failure?

Thanks

```
class ArticleController < InheritedResources::Base

  actions :show, :create, :update
  respond_to :html, :json

  before_filter :authorize_upsert, :only => [:create, :update]

  def create
    #init new game
    @article = Article.new

    set_article_attributes_from_app
    @article.is_published  = params[:article_publish_to_web] || false
    @ article.game_source  = @client_application

    create! do |success, failure|
      success.html {redirect_to(@article)}
      success.json {render :json => {:id=>@article.id, :created_at=>@article.created_at, :picture_urls=> @article.assets.map { |a| root_url.chop + a.photo.url}}}

      failure.html {render :action => "show"}
      failure.json {render :json=>@article.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}

    end

  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success.html {flash[:notice] = "Hurray!"; redirect_to(@article)}}

failure.html do 
  flash[:notice] = "All bad..."
  render :action => "show"
end
```

Just two ways of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [responders](http://github.com/plataformatec/responders) on its documentation.