# Custom Classes and Formatting on Flash Messages for Twitter Bootstrap defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am integrating twitter bootstrap css into my application. Going along just fine,but I don't know how to customize the css and wrappers for my flash messages.

I would like my flash messages to be formatted with the default Bootstrap classes:

```
    <div class="alert-message error">
      <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
      <p><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change this and that and <a href="#">try again</a>.</p>
    </div>
```

Currently I output my flash messages with:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
<% end %>
```

Is there an easy way to run a little switch that would make :notification or other rails flash messages map to the classes in bootcamp, like info?

Comment: try to see if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824271/how-to-customize-flash-message-based-on-success-or-failure-with-inherited-resour

Answer (score 55, accepted):

My answer for Bootstrap 2.0 starts from the helpful answer by @Railslerner but uses different code in the partial.

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb** (same as @Railslerner's answer)

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_class(level)
    case level.to_sym
    when :notice then "alert alert-info"
    when :success then "alert alert-success"
    when :error then "alert alert-error"
    when :alert then "alert alert-error"
    end
  end
end
```

Somewhere in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**:

```
<%= render 'layouts/flash_messages' %>
```

**app/views/layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="<%= flash_class(key) %> fade in">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Differences:

- Does not loop through different error levels each time it is called.
- Instead loops through the flash hash if the hash contains messages (following the
  [approach in Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec:the_flash)).
- Does not use the `<p>` tag, [no longer required](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts) in Bootstrap 2.0.

Remember to include bootstrap-alert.js so the fade and close functionality will work. If you're using the bootstap-sass gem, add this line to **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**:

```
//= require bootstrap-alert
```

---

**Update 8/9/2012:** Folders updated. I actually put everything except the helper under **app/views/layouts** since `flash_messages` is only used in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**.

**Update 6/5/2015:** After updating to Rails 4.2, I discovered that `level` was (at least sometimes) coming in as a String and failing to match the case statement in the ApplicationHelper. Changed that to `level.to_sym`.

Comment: @andkjaer, so flash is Nil? I'm not sure where the flash is instantiated. Does the flash work without the Bootstrap customizations, e.g. if you follow [Michael Hartl's instructions](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec:the_flash)?

Comment: Thanks! Works well. Any ideas on how to use this code when we are making an AJAX call to the conroller?

Comment: Sorry I haven't gotten into Ajax yet.  Maybe others will chime in.

Comment: Now in Bootstrap 4 need modify "fade in" for "fade show"

Answer (score 8):

Here's my answer with Bootstrap 2.0.0

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_class(level)
    case level
    when :notice then "alert alert-info"
    when :success then "alert alert-success"
    when :error then "alert alert-error"
    when :alert then "alert alert-error"
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/shared/_flash_messages.html.erb**

```
<% [:notice, :error, :alert].each do |level| %>
   <% unless flash[level].blank? %>
     <div class="<%= flash_class(level) %> fade in">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
       <%= content_tag :p, flash[level] %>
     </div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This gives you the fade out when closed and close button. If you were using HAML, checkout this guys post: http://ruby.zigzo.com/2011/10/02/flash-messages-twitters-bootstrap-css-framework/

Answer (score 6):

I am adding a new answer for Bootstrap 3.0 based on Mark Berry's answer. The Bootstrap CSS for alerts is at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def flash_class(level)
    case level
    when :notice then "alert-info"
    when :success then "alert-success"
    when :error then "alert-danger"
    when :alert then "alert-warning"
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable <%= flash_class(key) %> fade in">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Differences:

- Change Bootstrap classes for error and alert.
- Add `.alert-dismissable` and change the code for close button.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

application_helper.rb

```
def flash_class(level)
  case level
    when :notice then "info"
    when :error then "error"
    when :alert then "warning"
  end
end
```

and then

```
<% [:notice, :error, :alert].each do |level| %>
  <% unless flash[level].blank? %>
    <div data-alert="alert" class="alert-message <%= flash_class(level) %> fade in">
      <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
      <%= content_tag :p, flash[level] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I got the error msg `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass` for the code `<% unless flash[level].blank? %>`.

Comment: @ming Checkout my answer below (or above), using Bootstrap 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 3 class names (adjusted from Mark Berry's answer):

```
def flash_class(level)
  case level
    when :notice then "alert alert-info"
    when :success then "alert alert-success"
    when :error then "alert alert-danger"
    when :alert then "alert alert-warning"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding classes for the different notification levels used in rails:

```
.alert-notice {
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #eed3d7;
    color: #b94a48; }
```

etc.

and use them according to the examples from twitter bootstrap:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
        <%= value %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This makes a ApplicationHelper#flash_class(level) obsolete. It hardcodes styling into the application, which smells. Styling belongs into stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the ideal solution, but assuming you only ever use 'notice' or 'error' flash messages, you can use this:

```
...
<% content_tag :div, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "alert-message #{name == "notice" ? "success" : name}" do %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely alter the styling of the flash message--for example, if you don't want the message to fade, you can even do something like this:

In your controller:

```
flash[:order_error] = "This is an important error that shouldn't fade!"
```

Then compare the flash key to show the appropriate styling (with to_sym):

```
<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
  <% if key == 'order_error'.to_sym %>
    <div class="error" id="newErrorStyle"><%= msg %></div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="<%= key %>" id="flash-<%= key %>"><%= msg %></div>
    <% content_tag :script, :type => "text/javascript" do -%>
      setTimeout("new Effect.Fade('flash-<%= key %>');", 8000);
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```