# How do I get my Flash Message to show using bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have already imported bootstrap and I'm using the 'bootstrap-sass' gem and devise gem. The problem is My rails app shows the the right message like if am signed in and i try to sign up it shows the message 'You are already signed in.' but without the color around the message like yellow or red or any color.

```
 <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

When I inspect the element in chrome after it rendered I get 'class="alert alert-alert"'
In my code above the `"alert alert-#{name}"` the name is the key which should change to info, success, or warning or danger. but it keeps changing to alert which bootstrap doesn't have. How can i fix this?

Comment: How are you setting the flash message in your controller?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18913115/617320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by setting your flash message in your controller as `flash[:success]`, `flash[:info]`, `flash[:warning]` or `flash[:danger]`, as opposed to `flash[:alert]`.

For Devise, you will need to copy the Devise controllers into your Rails application to override these values. Alternatively, you can display the Bootstrap alerts manually if `flash[:notice]` or `flash[:alert]` are set:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:alert] %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <%= flash[:alert] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```